# Google Search Console - Should the https://, https://www., http://www, and the http:// be in the same set?

Tags: google-search, google-search-console

We started out with _http://... and quickly setup _http://www... (which we redirect to _http://...). A month or so ago, I finally get the SSL cert setup for our domain and now everything is automatically redirected to _https://www....

(1) Should I add all variants? 
(2) And should I set the https://www.domain.com as a primary?

There is quite a bit of traffic (hehe compared to what?)... ~15,000 unique users per day.

Comment: This question appears to belong on [Webmasters Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the variants apart from the one you're using is redundant, keep one set and you should be good to go.

Have you already added all the three variants?
I too had sites that have gone through the same process, we even had two properties in webmasters (one with www and the other without) - soon discovered that if we had 302 redirect setup, we had no use of the older versions.

BTW: 15k unique visitors is a pretty decent amount, hope you get more :)

Cheers!